# Is there an AJAX Anchor Link?

Tags: ajax

I want to use the classic anchor link to have a top nav link towards the bottom of the page. Is there an AJAX alternative for this to make it look cleaner and better?

Comment: Say what? You want a link on the bottom of your page? Then put it there in the HTML. You want a link on the top of the page to scroll you to the bottom? Then link it like <a href="#bottom">. You want it to scroll smoothly to the bottom? Then you need JS, not AJAX.

Comment: Down vote, question is too ambiguous and no follow up effort has been made.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confused between the terms Javascript and Ajax... I'm guessing you neeed an anchor link to smoothly animate or slide the scroller to the bottom/top of the page or to the anchor tag... check out this plugin [here](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/better-html-anchor-a-jquery-script-to-slide-the-scrollbar/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [jQuery LocalScroll plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/LocalScroll). There's [a nice demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/) to see all the ways to make scrolling nicer.